# How to copy a folder recursively in Rust?

Tags: rust

From what I see [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/index.html), there is no out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: It's a shame something like this is missing from the standard library...

Answer (score 20):

Simplest code that I've found works:

```rust
use std::path::Path;
use std::{io, fs};

fn copy_dir_all(src: impl AsRef<Path>, dst: impl AsRef<Path>) -> io::Result<()> {
    fs::create_dir_all(&dst)?;
    for entry in fs::read_dir(src)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        let ty = entry.file_type()?;
        if ty.is_dir() {
            copy_dir_all(entry.path(), dst.as_ref().join(entry.file_name()))?;
        } else {
            fs::copy(entry.path(), dst.as_ref().join(entry.file_name()))?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [fs_extra crate](https://github.com/webdesus/fs_extra) that I have written. This crate expands on the standard library `std::fs` and `std::io` modules.

It can (among other things):

- Copy files (optionally with information about the progress).
- Copy directories recursively (optionally with information about the progress).

Comment: Is that crate still being maintained? Last update was 2 years ago. (...Does it even need maintenance?)

Comment: All features from docs currently work. More features were added in git, but not yet published. By the end of the year, I want to find a time and add more new features. In the current moment i don't have time, but will glad see PR :)

Comment: Please provide some example usage of your crate too.

Comment: @Sreyasi think i wrote all cases in my [doc](https://docs.rs/fs_extra/1.1.0/fs_extra/)... Or I miss something?

Answer (score 11):

```
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

pub fn copy<U: AsRef<Path>, V: AsRef<Path>>(from: U, to: V) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    stack.push(PathBuf::from(from.as_ref()));

    let output_root = PathBuf::from(to.as_ref());
    let input_root = PathBuf::from(from.as_ref()).components().count();

    while let Some(working_path) = stack.pop() {
        println!("process: {:?}", &working_path);

        // Generate a relative path
        let src: PathBuf = working_path.components().skip(input_root).collect();

        // Create a destination if missing
        let dest = if src.components().count() == 0 {
            output_root.clone()
        } else {
            output_root.join(&src)
        };
        if fs::metadata(&dest).is_err() {
            println!(" mkdir: {:?}", dest);
            fs::create_dir_all(&dest)?;
        }

        for entry in fs::read_dir(working_path)? {
            let entry = entry?;
            let path = entry.path();
            if path.is_dir() {
                stack.push(path);
            } else {
                match path.file_name() {
                    Some(filename) => {
                        let dest_path = dest.join(filename);
                        println!("  copy: {:?} -> {:?}", &path, &dest_path);
                        fs::copy(&path, &dest_path)?;
                    }
                    None => {
                        println!("failed: {:?}", path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Other answers don't actually show how to do it, they just say how you *might* do it; here is a concrete example.

As discussed in the other answers, the relevant APIs are `fs::create_dir_all`, `fs::copy` and `fs::metadata`.

There is no 'all in one' standard library API for this.

Answer (score 6):

You could recursively walk the directory structure using [`std::fs::walk_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/std/fs/struct.WalkDir.html), which yields an iterator in a `Result`, and for each `Path`, check if it's a file using the [`is_file()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fs/trait.PathExtensions.html#tymethod.is_file) method provided by the `PathExtensions` extension trait. If it is, then use [`std::io::fs::copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fs/fn.copy.html) to actually copy the file.

Comment: All of those links are now broken.

Comment: First link should be relinked to https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/std/fs/struct.WalkDir.html (I made an edit, not sure whatever it will be accepted)

Answer (score 3):

`fs_extra` simply didn't work for me. Also it has confusing options, and the overall quality is suspicious (e.g. they think 64000 bytes is 64 kB).

Anyway an alternative which worked is [`copy_dir`](https://github.com/mdunsmuir/copy_dir) which contains a single function to do this, with no options. It won't overwrite existing directories, but you can probably modify the code to allow that pretty easily.

Comment: 64000 bytes is in fact 64 [kB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte).

64000 bytes is also 62.5 [KiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte).

Comment: KiB is horrible unit and mercifully most people do not use it. Using `kB` to refer to 1024 bytes is perfectly fine. In any case, the issue isn't about the name of the unit, it's about the fact that they think [64000 bytes is a sensible size for a buffer](https://github.com/webdesus/fs_extra/blob/d0dcf4a41ffdf83825b7511d206f37c841158117/src/file.rs#L32).

Comment: @Timmmm The binary prefixes are not horrible - they are unambiguous and can be easily pronounced. According to an IBM style guide "They are also required by EU law and in certain contexts in the US".

Comment: Regardless of naming, 64000 is still a weird size to use for IO, as the hardware and OS are highly likely to read power-of-two sized bytes/blocks. The OS will read 64kiB (or some larger amount) and then 1536 bytes will be left hanging around for the next call.

Answer (score 1):

A complete example of a program copying a directory content, using the crate [walkdir](https://docs.rs/walkdir/latest/walkdir/):

Let's start by listing the current files.

(Note: on windows `tree /F` list all files and directories)

```
$ tree /F

│   Cargo.lock
│   Cargo.toml
│
├───in
│   │   b.txt
│   │
│   └───dir_a
│           a.txt
│
└───src
        main.rs
```

### Rust sources

```
# File Cargo.toml

[package]
name = "plop"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
walkdir = "2" # latest version when writing this answer is 2.3
```

```rust
// File src/main.rs

use std::error::Error;
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use walkdir::WalkDir;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let in_dir = PathBuf::from("in");
    let out_dir = PathBuf::from("out");

    for entry in WalkDir::new(&in_dir) {
        let entry = entry?;
 
        let from = entry.path();
        let to = out_dir.join(from.strip_prefix(&in_dir)?);
        println!("\tcopy {} => {}", from.display(), to.display());

        // create directories
        if entry.file_type().is_dir() {
            if let Err(e) = fs::create_dir(to) {
                match e.kind() {
                    io::ErrorKind::AlreadyExists => {}
                    _ => return Err(e.into()),
                }
            }
        }
        // copy files
        else if entry.file_type().is_file() {
            fs::copy(from, to)?;
        }
        // ignore the rest
        else {
            eprintln!("copy: ignored symlink {}", from.display());
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

### Let's build and run it

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling winapi-util v0.1.5
   Compiling same-file v1.0.6
   Compiling walkdir v2.3.2
   Compiling plop v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Sam\Development\plop)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 6.33s
     Running `target\debug\plop.exe`
        copy in => out\
        copy in\b.txt => out\b.txt
        copy in\dir_a => out\dir_a
        copy in\dir_a\a.txt => out\dir_a\a.txt
```

Everything went well, let's again check files and directories.

```
$ tree /F

│   Cargo.lock
│   Cargo.toml
│
├───in
│   │   b.txt
│   │
│   └───dir_a
│           a.txt
│
├───out
│   │   b.txt
│   │
│   └───dir_a
│           a.txt
│
├───src
│       main.rs
| 
... # more content we can ignore, like the 'target' build directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I borrowed [Doug's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353820/doug) solution, but I think rayon makes the best bed sheets, so I did it with rayon. This is quick and dirty in that it doesn't handle any error cases (threads just crash instead of finishing) but you'll know when that happens if you use this as-is as it won't hide it. Should be easy to add your own error handling if you want it. I'm also a very amateurish programmer and my code shouldn't be used by anybody with any sense. I made it in such a way that you could use the indicatif crate to very easily add a nice looking progress bar.

When doing network copies of large folders of a ton of small files, this does the job pretty quickly in my tests.

No platform specific bits are used, so it should run anywhere that rust std compiles.

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use rayon::Scope;
use std::fs::{self, DirEntry};
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU64, Ordering};
use crossbeam::queue::SegQueue;
use rayon::iter::{ParallelIterator, IntoParallelRefIterator};

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
#[clap(name = "mtcopy", about = "Multi-threaded copy...in rust!")]
struct Opt {
    /// Source directory
    source: String,

    /// Destination directory
    dest: String,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Opt::parse();
    copy(&args.source, &args.dest);
}

fn copy<U: AsRef<Path>, V: AsRef<Path>>(from: &U, to: &V) {

    let start = std::time::Instant::now();
    let source = PathBuf::from(from.as_ref());
    let dest = PathBuf::from(to.as_ref());

    let total_size = AtomicU64::new(0);
    // Could possibly use dashmap for the bag instead, slower but it can be used to avoid duplicate files from e.g. symlinks
    let bag = SegQueue::new();
    rayon::scope(|s| scan(&source, &bag, s, &total_size));

    // Convert to a vec so that we can rayon it and throw the bag away
    let files = bag.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let total_size = total_size.into_inner();

    files.par_iter().for_each(|entry| {
        let entry = entry.as_ref().unwrap();
        let spath = entry.path();
        let stem = spath.strip_prefix(&source).unwrap();
        let dpath = dest.join(&stem);
        let size = entry.metadata().unwrap().len();
        fs::create_dir_all(&dpath.parent().unwrap()).unwrap();
        // println!("  copy: {:?} -> {:?}", &path, &dpath);
        fs::copy(&spath, &dpath).unwrap();
    });

    println!("Copied {} files, {} bytes in {}",  files.len(), total_size, start.elapsed().as_secs());
}

fn scan<'a, U: AsRef<Path>>(src: &U, bag: &'a SegQueue<Result<DirEntry, std::io::Error>>, s: &Scope<'a>, total_size: &'a AtomicU64) {
    let dir = fs::read_dir(src).unwrap();
    dir.into_iter().for_each(|entry| {
        let info = entry.as_ref().unwrap();
        let path = info.path();

        if path.is_dir() {
            s.spawn(move |s| scan(&path, bag, s, total_size))
        } else {
            // println!("{}", path.as_os_str().to_string_lossy());
            let filelength = info.metadata().unwrap().len();
            total_size.fetch_add(filelength, Ordering::SeqCst);
            bag.push(entry)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the active maintenance of [coreutils written in Rust](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils), we can simply reuse their rigorous `cp` implementation with `uu_cp = "0.0.24"` in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::path::PathBuf;

    // Equal to coreutils `cp -r src dst`
    fn uu_cp_recursive(src: PathBuf, dst: PathBuf) {
        let options = uu_cp::Options {
            attributes: uu_cp::Attributes::NONE, 
            attributes_only: false,
            copy_contents: false,
            cli_dereference: false,
            copy_mode: uu_cp::CopyMode::Copy,
            dereference: true,
            one_file_system: false,
            parents: false,
            update: uu_cp::UpdateMode::ReplaceAll,
            debug: false,
            verbose: false,
            strip_trailing_slashes: false,
            reflink_mode: uu_cp::ReflinkMode::Auto,
            sparse_mode: uu_cp::SparseMode::Auto,
            backup: uu_cp::BackupMode::NoBackup,
            backup_suffix: "~".to_owned(),
            no_target_dir: false,
            overwrite: uu_cp::OverwriteMode::Clobber(uu_cp::ClobberMode::Standard),
            recursive: true, // !
            target_dir: None,
            progress_bar: false
        };
        uu_cp::copy(&[src],  &dst, &options).unwrap();
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_cp() {
        uu_cp_recursive(PathBuf::from("/usr/bin"), PathBuf::from("/tmp"));
    }
}
```

The only inconvenient thing is that `uu_cp::Options` needs to be crafted manually, but it can be easily induced from [here](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/blob/5a2e0c700e279de7d5f20f96b029ce265768e9e6/src/uu/cp/src/cp.rs#L976) as I did (Do note a few difference regarding target OS). This shall behave exactly as `cp -r src dst` with most corner cases covered.